# Issue with jquery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, datatables

I am working with .net core 3.1

I have 4 record and I am trying to show data in jquery datatable

my console log successfully get the data but in the datatable not shown

[console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3beMT.png)

[and see this below error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnzlD.png)

[Immidiate Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar9v8.png)

HomeController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Data()
        {
            List<Student> customers = (from stud in this.studDBContext.students select stud).ToList();
            return Json(new { Data = customers });
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
<table class="table" id="studentdatatable"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
            <th>
                ImageCaption
            </th>
            <th>
                ImageDescription
            </th>
            <th>
                ImageName
            </th>
            @*<th>Mode</th>*@
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@* Load datatable css *@
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@* Load datatable js *@
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#studentdatatable').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "/Home/Data",
                type: "POST",
                //success: function (data) {
                //    debugger
                //    alert("success", data)
                //}
                
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "Id" },
                { data: "Name" },
                { data: "Address" },
                { data: "ImageCaption" },
                { data: "ImageDescription" },
                { data: "ImageName" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

why data now shown in datatable?

need help

Comment: My guess is that you need to use lower-case variable names in your column definitions. I.e. `data: "id"`

Comment: Use lowercase columns name, like this `{ data: "id" },`

Comment: @osmanRahimi yes issue solved thanks

Comment: @HansKilian issue solved thanks